# I need a query to count max cuncurrent connection for each user

Tags: mysql

I have this table log:

ID - MACDevice - USERNAME - startDateTime - stopDateTime - Duration

I need to fill the following table with statistic data:

MACDevice - MAXConcurrentConnection - DateTimeOccurred

I need only know the max values of  Concurrent Connections (When and How Many) for each MacDevice, if needed the monitored time interval could be 10 minutes, when I run the query (once a month)  I wish to query only the new log values and store them only if greatear than the stored values.
any help is welcome
thanks
luc

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT MACDevice, MAX(ConcurrentConnections) AS MAxConnections
FROM
  ( SELECT log1.*, COUNT(*) AS ConcurrentConnections
    FROM tableLog AS log1
      JOIN tableLog AS log2  
        AND log1.startDateTime <= log2.stopDateTime
        AND log2.startDateTime <= log1.stopDateTime
    GROUP BY log1.ID
  ) AS grp
GROUP BY MACDevice
```

**Warning**: with a big Log table, this query could be really slow.